# Adding a gameObject in an object in Unity3D

Tags: object, unity-game-engine

The question might seem a little too weird but I want to add the object "Capsule" to my gameobject using script (see the photo below)

[image: this is the image for the reference of "Capsule" object]

This is my code for adding components in my object:

```
object1 = (GameObject)Resources.Load (name) as GameObject;
        myObject = Instantiate (object1);
        myObject.transform.SetParent (parent.transform);
        myObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
        myObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (70f, 70f, 70f);
        myObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider> ();
        myObject.AddComponent<CapsuleCollider> ();
        myObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer> ();

        myObject.gameObject.SetActive (true);
```

What could be the possible solution for this? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your problem here ?

Comment: I want myObject to add the "Capsule" as a component. Is that possible?

Comment: It is not possible to add it as a Component. Do you mean as a children?

Comment: Uhm, yes as a children. Sorry

Comment: What does not work in your code? Do you have any error? Does `SetParent `works? We need more information about your issue here

Comment: Yes, it does work. I am adding multiple objects in the markerless parent but the capsule is only one even when i am adding multiple objects. I want it to be populated the same way my objects are being populated. I want my objects to have capsule in each of them. Is that possible?

Comment: You always attach the same object? `Instantiate` a new one each time you want to attach a new Capsule

Comment: No, i attach different 3d objects. How do i i add capsule for each 3d objects?

Comment: Make your capsule-adding logic into a method, and pass in a GameObject reference as a parameter. Then for each object just call the method and pass in a reference to it, to add the capsule to each one.

Comment: do you have a sample code for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding of what "Adding a `GameObject`" means so lets break this down. In Unity, a `GameObject` is a `Transform` and a collection of "*Components*". That `Transform` can be the "*parent*" or "*child*" of another `Transform`. `GameObjects` and their "*Transform Heirarchy*" are what's displayed in the "*Heirarchy*" Unity window. A single `GameObject` and its "*Components*" (things that implement `MonoBehaviour`) are what's displayed in the the "*Inspector*" Unity window.

By these terms, you *cannot* "Add a `GameObject` to another `GameObject`" however you *can* "Add a `GameObject` *as a child* of another `GameObject`" by parenting one `Transform` to another.

It seems like what you're trying to do here is add your "Capsule" as a child of each of your `GameObjects`.  All you need to do in this case is, for each `GameObject`, instantiate a new instance of the "Capsule" (it could be setup as a prefab) and parent it to your `GameObject`s:

```
public class CapsuleAdder : MonoBehaviour {
    private const string capsulePrefabName = "whatever"; // Prefab name goes here

    void Awake() {
        GameObject newCapsule = Instantiate(Resources.Load(capsulePrefabName) as GameObject) as GameObject;
        newCapsule.transform.SetParent(transform); // Sets parent to this
    }
}
```

As long as you properly set `capsulePrefabName`, any `GameObject` with this script attached will spawn a copy of your capsule prefab as a child.

Comment: should my capsule be added in the resources folder?

Comment: @Sarah Yes. `Resources.Load` will only work for assets in a "Resources" folder.

Comment: @Sarah I also forgot the call to `Instantiate` in my first pass. Edited the answer.